# Recursively search folder but exclude svn subfolder

Tags: grep

I want to find all occurences of `foo` in a large file system maintained by SVN but I don't want to match anything contained in any `.svn` directory.

I get immediate matches when I do `grep -l -e 'foo' *` but when I try and exclude the svn directories with `grep -l -e 'foo' --exclude-dir=".svn"` the command just hangs.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`--exclude-dir` does not supplant the need to list files on the command line.  You are "hanging" because `grep` is waiting for standard input.

```
grep -l -e 'foo' --exclude-dir=".svn" *
```

Consider using [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/), which excludes `.svn` and similar folders (and has many other features) by default.

Comment: Cleaner if you change `*` to `.`, in case there are other hidden folders that should be searched.

Comment: or perhaps you want to use `--recursive .` instead, seeing as the OP already has GNU `grep`.

Comment: Personally, I have `shopt -s dotglob` in Bash, so `*` already contains dot-files.  `-r` is nice, but `ack` does that by default too :)

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested in [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/).  It does recursive searching (and other grep-like operations), and excludes directories such as *.svn* or *.git* by default.

Comment: As a followup on this, I currently use [`ag`](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher), which similar, but faster.

Answer (score 1):

The `grep --exclude-dir...` solution should be fine, but just to show another way, you can do this with `find`'s `-prune`:

```
find -name .svn -prune -o -type f -exec grep -l "$pattern" {} +
```

If you want to execute something further, `find` is better than a plain `grep -r`:

```
find -name .svn -prune -o -type f -exec grep -q "$pattern" {} \; -exec ./process {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an awk solution as well:

```
find . | awk '$0 !~ /.svn/{print}' | awk '/foo/{print}'
```

Basically, from all files, prune those that match /.svn/ and then, out of those, print only these ones that match /foo/. I also like this solution as you can easily use the results with ls. For example, you can use

```
ls -tl $(find . | awk '$0 !~ /.svn/{print}' | awk '/foo/{print}')
```

to see a list view sorted by modification date. Also, it's nice to have the full path of the results if you want to do something else with them (open them, execute, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to grep into directories such as `.svn` ***ever*** you can set the `$GREP_OPTIONS` variable to exclude it as below:

```
export GREP_OPTIONS="--exclude-dir=\*/.svn/\*"
```

Just add this line to your `.bashrc` and your recursive greps will no more enter into `.svn` directories. Of course, it can be as rich as you want:

```
export GREP_OPTIONS="--exclude-dir=\*/.svn/\* --exclude-dir=\*/.hg/\* --exclude-dir=\*/.git/\* --exclude=\*~"
```

Comment: I personally do this using an alias so that I can bypass the exclusion list if I need to actually search inside those folders I can just use bare grep without having to unset/null out the variable. It also lets me maintain a list of folders that I can easily expand and have automatically added to my list of exclusions without having to do more typing.

Comment: That's a good approach. It also has the advantage that, if you need to grep into the folders, you will not forget you set a variable. (Not that I had ever needed to grep them.) But TBH these days I use [ag](https://geoff.greer.fm/ag/) (an ack clone) for these things ^^